# Лента событий в XML формате

Tags: python, xml, rss

Подскажите, каким образом можно добавить кастомные поля в rss-ленту?
Ведь у нее есть строгая [спецификация](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_134.html).

К примеру мне нужно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
<feed version="1.1">
  <events>
    <event id="93492" price="true" type="concert">
      <title><![CDATA[Kodaline]]></title>
      <age_restricted>18+</age_restricted>
      <tags>
        <tag>18+</tag>
        <tag>концерт</tag>
        <tag>рок и рок-н-ролл</tag>
      </tags>
      <gallery>
        <image href="***"/>
      </gallery>
      <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
    </event>
  <events>
</feed>
```

т.е. грубо говоря лента событий.

Как я предполагаю, это не может никаким образом относиться к RSS?
Есть ли какая либо спецификация для создания ленты событий?
Которую, к примеру, можно будет синхронизировать в google calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да. действительно.

в спецификации RSS указан строгий формат.
Это сделано для унификации интерфейсов оповещения о новых новостях.
Более полную свободу дает сам XML, в него можно вкладывать любые структуры данных.

Что касается лент событий ( events ), то строгого формата ( такого как для RSS-лент ) - нет. Например у мелкомягких [такой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968563(v=office.12).aspx).